# Bootstrap navbar goes into next section in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have been trying to figure out why my navbar doesn't expand itself when in mobile view, rather the menu ends up occupying the following section. I have tried playing around with static/fixed navbars, adding padding to the body, to no avail.

I'm also not sure about where I should be including my container-fluid. I've seen examples of it wrapping the entire navbar, while others only wrap the brand.

````
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Coins 4 Clothes</title>
    <!-- Stylesheets and libraries -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- CSS stylesheets-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <a class="navbar-md-brand" href="">
        <img class="img-fluid c4clogo" src="images/output-onlinepngtools.png" alt="Coins 4 Clothes logo">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">FAQ</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Register</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Log in</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </Nav>
    <hr class="hr-nav"></hr>

    <!-- Carousel section -->

    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class= "headings-slide1">
        <h2 class="headings-slides">De-clutter your closet.</h3>
        <h3 class="headings-slides">Help the needy.</h3>
        <h3 class="headings-slides">Earn Bitcoins.</h3>
        <hr class="hr-slides"></hr>
      </div>
      <img class="d-block w-10" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class= "headings-slide2">
        <h3 class="headings-slides">De-clutter your closet.</h3>
        <h2 class="headings-slides">Help the needy.</h2>
        <h3 class="headings-slides">Earn Bitcoins.</h3>
        <hr class="hr-slides"></hr>
      </div>
      <img class="d-block w-10" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class= "headings-slide3">
        <h3 class="headings-slides">De-clutter your closet.</h3>
        <h3 class="headings-slides">Help the needy.</h3>
        <h2 class="headings-slides">Earn Bitcoins.</h2>
        <hr class="hr-slides"></hr>
      </div>
      <img class="d-block w-10" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
    hello world
  </body> ```


and here is the CSS
````

Below is the CSS:

```
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Navigation Bar */


.navbar {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  height: 70px;
}

.navbar-md-brand {
  height: 70px;
  width: 276px;
padding-top: 10px;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 18px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: "ubuntu",sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link .navbar-toggler-icon {
  color: #21bf73;
}


/* Carousel */

.carousel-control-prev {
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.carousel-control-next {
  margin-right: -100px;
}

/* Download Buttons*/
.download-button {
  margin: 5% 3% 5% 0;
}

.headings-slides{
  padding-left: 20px;


}

.hr-slides{
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 30px;
}

.hr-nav{
margin-top: inherit;
border-top: 3px solid black;
}

h2{
  color: #478559;
  font-family: "ubuntu",sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to fix this. Since you are using a custom `.navbar-md-brand`, the simplest way is to set it like this:

```css
.navbar-md-brand {
  height: 70px;
  max-width: 276px;
  flex-grow: 1; /* let it "spread" until max-width */
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

For an ideal scenario, you need to check these breakpoints and "rewrite" `.navbar-md-brand` for corner cases, if you need
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

Or you can stay with the "official" way of doing things and use some of the existing classes like `class="navbar-brand mb-0"` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/#brand

Either way, hope these tips help you.